# Printing All Palindrome Numbers Within A Range Using The Number Of Digits Of The Numbers

Tags: java, palindrome

So I wrote my Palindrome program that is supposed to print all palindrome numbers between the range but it only seems to print 0 to 9 which means its evaluating all other numbers as false. I dont understand why?

```
public class Palindrome 
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        int number = 0;
        final int END = 10000;

        while (number <= END) 
        {
            if (isPalindrome(number)) 
            {
                System.out.print(" " + number);
            }

            number++;
        }
    }// end of main method 
    public static boolean isPalindrome(int number) 
    {
        //local variables 
        int counter = 0;
        int numDigits = 0;
        final int END = 10000;
        boolean palindrome = false;


        while (number <= 10000)
        {
            //formula for finding the number of digits in a number
            numDigits = getNumDigits(number);

            //special case if number = 0
            if (numDigits == 1)
            {
                palindrome = true;
                break;
            } 

                if(counter < numDigits / 2)
                {
                    if (((number / (int) Math.pow(10, counter)) % 10) != (number / (int) Math.pow(10, numDigits - counter - 1)))
                    {
                        palindrome = false;
                        counter++;

                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        palindrome = true;
                    }

                }

            number++;


        }// end of loop
        return palindrome;

    }//end of isPalindrome Method
    public static int getNumDigits(int number)
    {
        //local variables

        int numDigits = (int) (Math.log10(number) + 1);

            if(number == 0) 
            { 
                numDigits = 1;
            }

        return numDigits; 

    }//end of getNumDigits method


}
```

Comment: Fire up your debugger and see for yourself.

Comment: i dont have a debugger

Comment: Then get a normal IDE (like Eclipse). It's free.

Answer (score -1):

My first suggestion would be to log the output of your various methods to ensure you are getting back the correct output.  Using System.out.println() can help with this as I see you don't have access to a debugger.

Also, as for your isPalindrome() function.  I don't know if you have any restrictions where you have to use math functions but you could do something along these lines there:

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(int number) {
    String numString = number + "";
    for(int i = 0; i < numString.length() / 2; i++){
        if(numString.charAt(i) != numString.charAt(numString.length() - i){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

This essentially checks each character in the String representation of your number against it's corresponding character at the end of the String.  You can divide the condition by 2 because after the half way point you have already checked the equality of the characters.

Warning, I may have some off by one errors in this.  I didn't test it.  I'm just trying to give some ideas and a starting point.

Good luck!