# Java program to find palindrome numbers in given range

Tags: java, palindrome

I am trying to find **Palindrome** numbers in a given range. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PalindromeNums{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int start,end,rem,rev=0,temp;
        ArrayList <Integer> palindrome = new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.print("Start : ");
        start = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("End : ");
        end = input.nextInt();

        temp = start;
        for(int i = start; i <= end; i++){

            while(temp != 0){
                rem = temp % 10;
                rev = rev * 10 + rem;
                temp = temp / 10;
            }

            System.out.println(rev);
            if(i == rev){
                palindrome.add(i);
            }
            temp++;
            rev = 0;
        }
        System.out.println(palindrome);

    }
}
```

When I run the code, it's giving the right output for the first integer only. It's not working for other integers in the given range. 
Any suggestion/solution for this problem? And why it's not working?

**Sample output:**

> Start : 33 End : 55 33 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
>   [33]

Comment: Can you give a sample for it's not working?

Comment: Did you try to use a debugger to debug this?

Comment: HI
Please check this screenshot : https://i.imgur.com/zRlBj7z.png
Check the output

Comment: Please edit the question with updated information, marking the edit clearly, and try to avoid images and post text wherever possible.

Comment: Thanks KevinO for your suggestion. I have added sample output. I don't know if I will need to add anything else

Comment: may it will helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33815164/printing-all-palindrome-numbers-within-a-range-using-the-number-of-digits-of-the

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your temp is not incrementing by 1 in the loop.

```
// temp is initialized to start at first
while(temp != 0){
    rem = temp % 10;
    rev = rev * 10 + rem;
    temp = temp / 10;
}
// at the end of this temp's value is entirely changed.
// above temp is incremented here, ideally temp at the start should be incremented. You can do this by initializing temp as i
temp++;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PalindromeNums{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int start,end,rem,rev=0,temp;
        ArrayList <Integer> palindrome = new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.print("Start : ");
        start = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("End : ");
        end = input.nextInt();

     // Picking Each Number Of That Range;
        for(int i = start; i <= end; i++){
            temp =i;
            // Checking whether Its Palindrome Or Not
            while(temp != 0){
                rem = temp % 10;
                rev = rev * 10 + rem;
                temp = temp / 10;
            }

            System.out.println(rev);
            if(i == rev){
                palindrome.add(i);
            }
            rev = 0;
        }
        System.out.println(palindrome);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By the time the loop ends, `temp` will be 0 and hence you should not be doing `temp++`.

Rather, you need to assign the current number being processed to `temp` as the first line of the *for* loop as

```
temp = i;
```